# 404- page not found error while accessing flowplayer.unlimited-3.2.7.swf file

Tags: flash

I have an application that plays video on the web. It uses flowplayer.unlimited-3.2.7.swf to play it and has the other related swf files for captions and audio. We are able to play it in our application in our domain, say www.aaa.com/.../flowplayer-unlimited.swf. However, we have a functionality where the user can create an iframe with the url pointing to a different site, say w.playvid.com, save it to a file and later open up the file, click on the URL at which point it directs it to w.playvid.com..../flowplayer-unlimited.swf, at which point it is supposed to start playing the video. However, I am running into an 404 - page not found error. I think it may have to do with the flash setting or permissions, but I am not sure what exactly or how to resolve this.

Also, I am able to access image files in the same folder as the flowplayer from the outside url, i.e. w.playvid.com .

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

thanks in advance,

Asha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a problem getting a `404` error with my `flowplayer.swf` file and it had to do with my `.htaccess` file.

Are you using CodeIgniter and rewriting URLs to put the `index.php` reference into your URLs?

If so, the issue could be caused by your `.htaccess` file mapping the flash file to an incorrect path that includes `index.php`.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks David. Sorry to post the response so late. It worked for me.